# AngularJS 1.4 - CRUD - Not able to add dummy JSON data

Tags: json, angularjs

I am trying to simple CRUD in AngularJS 1.4 and here is the link.

http://plnkr.co/edit/N7GOW17PaUGEYSgz1zut?p=preview

When I try to add a employee in the JSON string using below code it is not working.

```
$scope.employees.push($scope.employee);
```

Reference: I followed this tutorial which uses older version of AngularJS
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5uhZCc0j9RY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Controllers are not singletons, they are initiated each time a page is loaded that requests them. Your `addController` is actually updating your `employees` value, but then `$location.path()` is navigating back to the `listController`, which is re-running and resetting your `employees`.

One solution to this issue comes with the use of a service.  Instead of defining `employes` on `$scope`, you can create a service which holds these contents.  Services are singletons, and can be injected into any controller which needs access to these properties.

```
crudApp.service('employeeService', function(){
  this.employees = [{
    name: 'Jay',
    city: 'London',
    age: '36'
  }, {
    name: 'Mohan',
    city: 'Chennai',
    age: '44'
  }];
});

crudApp.controller('listController', function($scope, employeeService) {
  $scope.employees = employeeService.employees;
});

crudApp.controller('addController', function($scope, $location, employeeService) {
  $scope.employee = {
    name: "",
    city: "",
    age: ""
  };

  $scope.add = function() {
    employeeService.employees.push($scope.employee);
    $location.path('/');
  };
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/HkCrmu1IFqnoyn62bPUt?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

It is adding the employee. The problem is that after adding the employee, you are reloading the page, which effectively reloads the application and resets the initial state. Since you are working with an in-memory list, changes are lost. If you don't have a database, consider using local storage.